# Google Cloud Platform int64_field_0

Tags: python, csv

We are getting an extra column 'int64_field_0' while loading data from CSV to BigTable in GCP. Is there any way to avoid this first column. We are using the method load_table_from_file and setting option AutoDetect Schema as True. Any suggestions please. Thanks.

Comment: How are you loading the CSV file?  Can you point me at a website with instructions?  That would give us more information in order to help you.

Comment: Is the `int64_field_0` in your CSV file? If so, can you just remove it from the file before loading?

Comment: Using Pandas Data frame to_csv method. May be excel index field causing problem? I will check again by passing index=False attribute.

Comment: pd.to_csv(filename, index=False) did solve the problem. Thanks for taking time to answer my query.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, using Pandas Data Frame's `pd.to_csv(filename, index=false)` resolved the issue.